# MSAL - get user name on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure-ad-msal

Recently we've implemented a sign in/up mechanism in our app using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) Objective-C library. Everything works great, however now we want to display the name of the currently signed in user.

There is `username` public property in MSALAccount class - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/blob/dev/MSAL/src/public/MSALAccount.h#L37, but most of the time it contains either `nil` or some string like "Missing from the token response".

There is also a private/internal property called `name` (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/blob/dev/MSAL/src/MSALAccount%2BInternal.h#L52) in the same MSALAccount class. We've noticed during debugging that this property contains the proper user name (e.g. user name on Facebook, if user signed in via FB), while `username` property still contains `nil`.

Does anybody know a way to get this `name` property value except for:

- calling private API (e.g. `performSelector:`)
- looking into the source code of the library and replicating the logic
  of getting prop value

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue w/B2C and MSAL. The reason is because B2C does not return a value in the IdToken for preferred username because of the limitations with the social accounts. For example, AAD does return a value here because it knows who the user is, but for b2c, because the user can sign in with a local account, FB, Github, Amazon, etc...there is not a consistent value for them to use for preferred username. Also, some social accounts (like Github) don't require email. So...to unblock MSAL from rolling out cache compatibility with ADAL, MSAL decided to use "Missing from the token response" on their end when dealing with the B2C accounts because it would be schema violation for it to be null. In those cases, were the preferred username in the IdToken is null, MSAL adds a constant "Missing from the token response".

You can, however, use the "name" claim as the preferred username. I believe you can add that in the policy. It's generally mentioned in this [B2C doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#frequently-asked-questions) -> "In the Return claim column, choose claims you want returned in the authorization tokens sent back to your application after a successful profile editing experience. For example, select Display Name, Postal Code.”

Comment: if possible can you please explain the steps to fix the issue.

Comment: which issue specifically @TARUN?